# How to load a child component of a relation in Strapi

Tags: node.js, mongoose, content-management-system, strapi

In my Strapi application, I have the following structure:

Footer(single type) > Section(component) > Menu(collection type) > link(component)

When performing a query Strapi only returns the id of the link and I needed its LABEL and URL, does anyone know how I can bring this in a query only?

[Strapi section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjcE.png)

[Link Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3Qz.png)

[Footer API return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUfwf.png)

I used this topic on the Strapi forum, but without success yet

https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-do-i-return-only-selected-fields-from-the-model-and-its-relation/1115/2

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer; im new to Strapi.

The Strapi get requests only populates with relational data in a single layer of nesting. Your links looks to be on the second layer.

You have two options:

1. Query for the links by ID from your client after receiving the IDs. This can be done efficiently using Promise.all.
2. Modify the default GET handler for the ressource in the Strapi code. Extend the query to join on your links, and return the response in its entirity.

Update on option 2;

You can customize the logic behind any single endpoint handler in the API in your Strapi backend. The process is best descriped in their documentation on [Custom Data Response's](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/custom-data-response.html#introduction). Note that the syntax on how to query the database is based on a popular ORM depending on your database of choice. The ORMs are:

- MongoDB (through Mongoose)
- Postgres, MySQL, SQLite3 and more (through Bookshelf)
- Redis (through ioredis).

Comment: Hi Markido, thanks for your response.
Option #1 is not possible in my case, I need to send it all in just one JSON.
Do you have any example of option #2?

Comment: Hi @CleversonFranco - will you let me know if the updated answer is of any help? :-)